# What insect is this? (Black body two orange lines in its back and six legs)

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I found this today in the library while studying. I am very curious to know whether this particular insect has a name that I can look up and find more information about:

[image]

Full length is almost one centimeter. It doesn't bite or anything. It has lots of small hairs in its back (similar to cockroaches and ants) and has a tail that a white sticky substance comes out from.

Comment: where in the world are you?

Comment: That is awesome. I have them all over a very large potted flower I have on my front porch. Which also have a lot of aphid on it so assume that is why they are there., ( to eat the aphid ) I do know ladybugs love to eat aphid so this is good as I do not like to put pesticides on my plants or gardens. And I live on the eastern side of Washington State which is very dry and has lots of little critters all over your gardens. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this yellowish insect?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51491/what-is-this-yellowish-insect)

Answer (score 16):

It's a [larvae from a ladybird (or ladybug)](http://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_ladybirds/).  Judging by the stripe pattern it is a [Common Spotted Ladybird](http://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_ladybirds/CommonSpotted.htm) (wiki: *[Harmonia conformis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonia_conformis)*) and from the body shape & size I'd also say [3rd instar](http://www.flickr.com/photos/burtonandy/4628261516/).

The one you have photographed, and the one on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/burtonandy/4628261516/), are larval forms of the ladybug, just like when a catepillar becomes a butterfly, the ladybugs also have a [larval stage in their life cycle](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/insects/Ladybug.shtml) which crawl around and look very different to the adult form.

Comment: It is definitely this one: http://www.flickr.com/photos/burtonandy/4628261516/ I just cant understand why the photo of the insect in wikipedia is totally different with this one!

Comment: @dane The one you have photographed and the one on flickr are larval forms of the ladybug, just like when a catepillar becomes a butterfly, the ladybugs also have larvae which crawl around and look very different to the adult form. http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/insects/Ladybug.shtml

Comment: Wow. I've seen these around a bunch, but I had _no clue_ that they were ladybug larvae. That's wild!