# What is this yellowish insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this insect inside of my shoe. It is approximately 1cm in length and less than half a centimetre wide. It was found in the Netherlands, in the province Gelderland.

Close shot

[image]

Distant shot

[image]

Upside down

[image]

*What kind of insect is that?*

Edit:

As @fileunderwater suggested: the question is "close" but not identical.
I think that the suggested duplicate will only provide an identification of the family of the insect, but nothing more precise and specific. Therefore, the answers for the 2 questions vary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What insect is this? (Black body two orange lines in its back and six legs)](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/what-insect-is-this-black-body-two-orange-lines-in-its-back-and-six-legs)

Comment: @rg255 Its probably reasonable to close this as duplicate, but strictly speaking these are probably two different species (I'm not into Coccinellidae larvae). So a more general question is to what extent we should close questions as duplicates if they are "close" but not identical (for species-id Qs, similar at what taxonomic level)? Here, the proposed duplicate will provide a family id, but that is all. So comparing to mammals, equal to answering "this is a deer" to a species-id Q with a picture of an Moose.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is the larva of *Harmonia axyridis* (Asian lady beetle).

[image]

The image posted by [timbernasley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS5vd.jpg) is more accurate because the larva you have shown is in its late instar ,a stage not an early as this one.

[image: Image2]
Here's the link: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonia_axyridis)

Comment: Note that this is not the same as what is commonly called the "Lady Bug" in North America.

Comment: As we should all hopefully know, lady bugs/birds/beetles are a beneficial species, so try not to kill any larvae you see.  However, do be aware that larvae have been known to bite, so take care in relocating it.

Comment: @n_b although this is the Harlequin ladybird larvae which is a very aggressive invasive species currently wiping out the native population of the UK

Comment: @n_b No, this one is Harmonia, kill it on sight.

Comment: @Ilythya & Vladimir I stand corrected. I didn't know it was an invasive species. Kill these.

Comment: @n_b Good luck on killing them; this invasive species is now the most common ladybug in urban areas in the Netherlands. :-(

Answer (score 11):

This is a ladybug larva:
[google image search](https://www.google.de/search?q=ladybug%20larvae&client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1920&bih=922&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwizrOrUpYnPAhXGyRQKHRS6BkYQsAQIGw#tbm=isch&q=ladybug%20larva)

[image]