# Can you identify this insect (orange back, 6 legs)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found a couple of them in central europe on a zucchini plant (in august).

They are about a centimeter in size.

Tried looking for insect with orange back and 6 legs but no result.

[**EDIT** from comment]: [The insect in this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/what-insect-is-this-black-body-two-orange-lines-in-its-back-and-six-legs?rq=1) looks pretty similar. There is a difference though - the one in my picture has orange legs not black ones. (maybe different stage of larvae or different species of ladybug or just random?)

Comment: There is a related question and answer here which identifies a similar creature as the larval form of a 'spotted lady bug' or beetle; and this is probably what you noticed.  Another possibility is the larval form of a burying beetle (Nicrophorus), but that's less likely.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, [that's it](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/what-insect-is-this-black-body-two-orange-lines-in-its-back-and-six-legs?rq=1) ... one difference though, the one on my picture has orange legs not black ones

Comment: If you find more, and they are larvae, you just have to watch what they turn into.  Right.  I'm not an expert but the related question was too obvious not to let you know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a harlequin ladybird larvae.

[image]

This is one of the most variable species in the world, with an unusually broad range of color forms. It is native to eastern Asia, but has been artificially introduced to North America and Europe to control aphids.

I figure that Wiki is saying "it has some of the highest color variability of any wild plant or animal".

[image]

wiki: [harlequin ladybird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonia_axyridis)